# Animation when changing divs

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I'm struggling on changing gallery sets animation.

So far I've reached just a simple "fade" effect using opacity in @keyframes applied on .gallery-set.

I know it's a very common thing, but I can't find anything that would help me and make me understand how it works. I don't want any plugins or libraries for it. I just want to learn how to do that in pure html, css and js.

My goal is : When clicking on the menu, gallery set will change - current will slide to left and fadeout and new one will slide from right to place where previous were. (Hope I've explained it well :D ).

I've tried to add in @keyframes galleryfade transform : translateX, but I don't know what to do next.

I'm new to these things, learning JS at home on my own, so every bit of advise would be helpful to me. Thanks to everybody who will spend time on this.

CodePen link : https://codepen.io/pinnci/pen/YzydPdq

```js
let menuLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.work-menu li a');
let gallerySets = document.querySelectorAll('.gallery-set');

gallerySets.forEach(set => {
    set.classList.add('displayNone');
});

function showGallery(id){
    gallerySets.forEach(set => {
        if(set.id == id){
            set.classList.remove('displayNone');
            set.style.opacity = '1';
        }else{
            set.classList.add('displayNone');
            set.style.opacity = '0';
        }
    });

    menuLinks.forEach(link => {
        if(link.id == id){
            link.classList.add('selected');
        }else{
            link.classList.remove('selected');
        }
    });
}

menuLinks.forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        showGallery(item.id);
    });
});

showGallery('healthcare');
```

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
}

.container{
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.o-hidden{
    overflow: hidden;
}

img{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.works{
    padding:1em 0 3em 0 ;
}

.works h2{
    font-size: 2em;
}

.work-menu ul{
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0;
}

.work-menu a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:black;
    transition: 0.1s;
    padding: 0.2em 0 ;
}

.selected{
    border-bottom: 0.1em solid #f3bb28;
}

.work-menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 1em;
}

.work-menu a:hover{
    color:#f3bb28;
}

.gallery-set img{
    margin: 0.5em;
    transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
    width: 20%;
}

.gallery-set img:hover{
    transform: scale(1.03);
    cursor: pointer;
}


/*GALLERY SETS*/
.displayNone{
    display: none;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

.gallery-set{
    animation: galleryFade .4s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes galleryFade{
    from{
        opacity: 0.3;
    }
    to{
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="works">
   <div class="container">
       <h2>RECENT WORKS</h2>

        <div class="work-menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" id="healthcare">Healthcare</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" id="education">Education</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" id="goverment">Goverment</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" id="commercial">Commercial</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
                            <div class="gallery-set" id="healthcare">
                <img src="https://cdn3.wpbeginner.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/ultimate-small-business-resource-coronavirus.png" id="1">
                <img src="https://cdn3.wpbeginner.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/ultimate-small-business-resource-coronavirus.png" id="2">
                <img src="https://cdn3.wpbeginner.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/ultimate-small-business-resource-coronavirus.png" id="3">
                <img src="https://cdn3.wpbeginner.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/ultimate-small-business-resource-coronavirus.png" id="4">
                <img src="https://cdn3.wpbeginner.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/ultimate-small-business-resource-coronavirus.png" id="5">
                <img src="https://cdn3.wpbeginner.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/ultimate-small-business-resource-coronavirus.png" id="6">
                <img src="https://cdn3.wpbeginner.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/ultimate-small-business-resource-coronavirus.png" id="7">
                <img src="https://cdn3.wpbeginner.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/ultimate-small-business-resource-coronavirus.png" id="8">
            </div>

            <div class="gallery-set" id="education">
                <img src="https://blog.mares.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/photo-by-Janez-Kranjc-3-Large-550x320.jpg" id="9">
                <img src="https://blog.mares.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/photo-by-Janez-Kranjc-3-Large-550x320.jpg" id="10">
                <img src="https://blog.mares.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/photo-by-Janez-Kranjc-3-Large-550x320.jpg" id="11">
                <img src="https://blog.mares.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/photo-by-Janez-Kranjc-3-Large-550x320.jpg" id="12">
                <img src="https://blog.mares.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/photo-by-Janez-Kranjc-3-Large-550x320.jpg" id="13">
                <img src="https://blog.mares.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/photo-by-Janez-Kranjc-3-Large-550x320.jpg" id="14">
                <img src="https://blog.mares.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/photo-by-Janez-Kranjc-3-Large-550x320.jpg" id="15">
                <img src="https://blog.mares.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/photo-by-Janez-Kranjc-3-Large-550x320.jpg" id="16">
            </div>

            <div class="gallery-set" id="goverment">
                <img src="https://bsscommerce.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/how-to-customize-order-id-550x320.png" id="17">
                <img src="https://bsscommerce.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/how-to-customize-order-id-550x320.png" id="18">
                <img src="https://bsscommerce.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/how-to-customize-order-id-550x320.png" id="19">
                <img src="https://bsscommerce.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/how-to-customize-order-id-550x320.png" id="20">
                <img src="https://bsscommerce.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/how-to-customize-order-id-550x320.png" id="21">
                <img src="https://bsscommerce.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/how-to-customize-order-id-550x320.png" id="22">
                <img src="https://bsscommerce.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/how-to-customize-order-id-550x320.png" id="23">
                <img src="https://bsscommerce.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/how-to-customize-order-id-550x320.png" id="24">
            </div>

            <div class="gallery-set" id="commercial">
                <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/2GOR8jFYc-c4ueS2RnoQdshYBKcSa8Vt2UsL3VMqiFbjCqn1y0Xl_l4RalzP-rYmGYyq3oKJp_pjzcyfvG_oAowHWWi2fAxFmrp8ccbzlCSDsRxOfUtuOSpqHbepUoqSloxWZVWsKMDrmkWaLV09utnR2ACHfrQ0FS1yeSKkQNevmk8g" id="25">
                <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/2GOR8jFYc-c4ueS2RnoQdshYBKcSa8Vt2UsL3VMqiFbjCqn1y0Xl_l4RalzP-rYmGYyq3oKJp_pjzcyfvG_oAowHWWi2fAxFmrp8ccbzlCSDsRxOfUtuOSpqHbepUoqSloxWZVWsKMDrmkWaLV09utnR2ACHfrQ0FS1yeSKkQNevmk8g" id="26">
                <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/2GOR8jFYc-c4ueS2RnoQdshYBKcSa8Vt2UsL3VMqiFbjCqn1y0Xl_l4RalzP-rYmGYyq3oKJp_pjzcyfvG_oAowHWWi2fAxFmrp8ccbzlCSDsRxOfUtuOSpqHbepUoqSloxWZVWsKMDrmkWaLV09utnR2ACHfrQ0FS1yeSKkQNevmk8g" id="27">
                <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/2GOR8jFYc-c4ueS2RnoQdshYBKcSa8Vt2UsL3VMqiFbjCqn1y0Xl_l4RalzP-rYmGYyq3oKJp_pjzcyfvG_oAowHWWi2fAxFmrp8ccbzlCSDsRxOfUtuOSpqHbepUoqSloxWZVWsKMDrmkWaLV09utnR2ACHfrQ0FS1yeSKkQNevmk8g" id="28">
                <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/2GOR8jFYc-c4ueS2RnoQdshYBKcSa8Vt2UsL3VMqiFbjCqn1y0Xl_l4RalzP-rYmGYyq3oKJp_pjzcyfvG_oAowHWWi2fAxFmrp8ccbzlCSDsRxOfUtuOSpqHbepUoqSloxWZVWsKMDrmkWaLV09utnR2ACHfrQ0FS1yeSKkQNevmk8g" id="29">
                <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/2GOR8jFYc-c4ueS2RnoQdshYBKcSa8Vt2UsL3VMqiFbjCqn1y0Xl_l4RalzP-rYmGYyq3oKJp_pjzcyfvG_oAowHWWi2fAxFmrp8ccbzlCSDsRxOfUtuOSpqHbepUoqSloxWZVWsKMDrmkWaLV09utnR2ACHfrQ0FS1yeSKkQNevmk8g" id="30">
                <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/2GOR8jFYc-c4ueS2RnoQdshYBKcSa8Vt2UsL3VMqiFbjCqn1y0Xl_l4RalzP-rYmGYyq3oKJp_pjzcyfvG_oAowHWWi2fAxFmrp8ccbzlCSDsRxOfUtuOSpqHbepUoqSloxWZVWsKMDrmkWaLV09utnR2ACHfrQ0FS1yeSKkQNevmk8g" id="31">
                <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/2GOR8jFYc-c4ueS2RnoQdshYBKcSa8Vt2UsL3VMqiFbjCqn1y0Xl_l4RalzP-rYmGYyq3oKJp_pjzcyfvG_oAowHWWi2fAxFmrp8ccbzlCSDsRxOfUtuOSpqHbepUoqSloxWZVWsKMDrmkWaLV09utnR2ACHfrQ0FS1yeSKkQNevmk8g" id="32">
            </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified the code in order to execute the second part and show you the code so that you can modify it to your liking by adding other animations ;)
The main change was made by changing the animation with a lateral movement and 0 opacity as it already was.

```js
 let menuLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.work-menu li a');
let gallerySets = document.querySelectorAll('.gallery-set');

gallerySets.forEach(set => {
    set.classList.add('displayNone');
});

function showGallery(id){
    gallerySets.forEach(set => {
        if(set.id == id){
            set.classList.remove('displayNone');
            set.style.opacity = '1';
        }else{
            set.classList.add('displayNone');
            set.style.opacity = '0';
        }
    });

    menuLinks.forEach(link => {
        if(link.id == id){
            link.classList.add('selected');
        }else{
            link.classList.remove('selected');
        }
    });
}

menuLinks.forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        showGallery(item.id);
    });
});

showGallery('healthcare');
```

```css
        body{
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
}

.container{
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.o-hidden{
    overflow: hidden;
}

img{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.works{
    padding:1em 0 3em 0 ;
}

.works h2{
    font-size: 2em;
}

.work-menu ul{
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0;
}

.work-menu a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:black;
    transition: 0.1s;
    padding: 0.2em 0 ;
}

.selected{
    border-bottom: 0.1em solid #f3bb28;
}

.work-menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 1em;
}

.work-menu a:hover{
    color:#f3bb28;
}

.gallery-set img{
    margin: 0.5em;
    transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
    width: 20%;
}

.gallery-set img:hover{
    transform: scale(1.03);
    cursor: pointer;
}


/*GALLERY SETS*/
.displayNone{
    display: none;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

.gallery-set{
    animation: galleryFade .4s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes galleryFade{
    from{
  transform: translateX(450px);  
  opacity: 0;
    }
    to{
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="works">
        <div class="container">
            <h2>RECENT WORKS</h2>

            <div class="work-menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" id="healthcare">Healthcare</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" id="education">Education</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" id="goverment">Goverment</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" id="commercial">Commercial</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
                            <div class="gallery-set" id="healthcare">
                <img src="https://cdn3.wpbeginner.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/ultimate-small-business-resource-coronavirus.png" id="1">
                <img src="https://cdn3.wpbeginner.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/ultimate-small-business-resource-coronavirus.png" id="2">
                <img src="https://cdn3.wpbeginner.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/ultimate-small-business-resource-coronavirus.png" id="3">
                <img src="https://cdn3.wpbeginner.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/ultimate-small-business-resource-coronavirus.png" id="4">
                <img src="https://cdn3.wpbeginner.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/ultimate-small-business-resource-coronavirus.png" id="5">
                <img src="https://cdn3.wpbeginner.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/ultimate-small-business-resource-coronavirus.png" id="6">
                <img src="https://cdn3.wpbeginner.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/ultimate-small-business-resource-coronavirus.png" id="7">
                <img src="https://cdn3.wpbeginner.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/ultimate-small-business-resource-coronavirus.png" id="8">
            </div>

            <div class="gallery-set" id="education">
                <img src="https://blog.mares.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/photo-by-Janez-Kranjc-3-Large-550x320.jpg" id="9">
                <img src="https://blog.mares.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/photo-by-Janez-Kranjc-3-Large-550x320.jpg" id="10">
                <img src="https://blog.mares.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/photo-by-Janez-Kranjc-3-Large-550x320.jpg" id="11">
                <img src="https://blog.mares.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/photo-by-Janez-Kranjc-3-Large-550x320.jpg" id="12">
                <img src="https://blog.mares.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/photo-by-Janez-Kranjc-3-Large-550x320.jpg" id="13">
                <img src="https://blog.mares.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/photo-by-Janez-Kranjc-3-Large-550x320.jpg" id="14">
                <img src="https://blog.mares.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/photo-by-Janez-Kranjc-3-Large-550x320.jpg" id="15">
                <img src="https://blog.mares.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/photo-by-Janez-Kranjc-3-Large-550x320.jpg" id="16">
            </div>

            <div class="gallery-set" id="goverment">
                <img src="https://bsscommerce.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/how-to-customize-order-id-550x320.png" id="17">
                <img src="https://bsscommerce.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/how-to-customize-order-id-550x320.png" id="18">
                <img src="https://bsscommerce.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/how-to-customize-order-id-550x320.png" id="19">
                <img src="https://bsscommerce.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/how-to-customize-order-id-550x320.png" id="20">
                <img src="https://bsscommerce.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/how-to-customize-order-id-550x320.png" id="21">
                <img src="https://bsscommerce.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/how-to-customize-order-id-550x320.png" id="22">
                <img src="https://bsscommerce.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/how-to-customize-order-id-550x320.png" id="23">
                <img src="https://bsscommerce.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/how-to-customize-order-id-550x320.png" id="24">
            </div>

            <div class="gallery-set" id="commercial">
                <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/2GOR8jFYc-c4ueS2RnoQdshYBKcSa8Vt2UsL3VMqiFbjCqn1y0Xl_l4RalzP-rYmGYyq3oKJp_pjzcyfvG_oAowHWWi2fAxFmrp8ccbzlCSDsRxOfUtuOSpqHbepUoqSloxWZVWsKMDrmkWaLV09utnR2ACHfrQ0FS1yeSKkQNevmk8g" id="25">
                <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/2GOR8jFYc-c4ueS2RnoQdshYBKcSa8Vt2UsL3VMqiFbjCqn1y0Xl_l4RalzP-rYmGYyq3oKJp_pjzcyfvG_oAowHWWi2fAxFmrp8ccbzlCSDsRxOfUtuOSpqHbepUoqSloxWZVWsKMDrmkWaLV09utnR2ACHfrQ0FS1yeSKkQNevmk8g" id="26">
                <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/2GOR8jFYc-c4ueS2RnoQdshYBKcSa8Vt2UsL3VMqiFbjCqn1y0Xl_l4RalzP-rYmGYyq3oKJp_pjzcyfvG_oAowHWWi2fAxFmrp8ccbzlCSDsRxOfUtuOSpqHbepUoqSloxWZVWsKMDrmkWaLV09utnR2ACHfrQ0FS1yeSKkQNevmk8g" id="27">
                <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/2GOR8jFYc-c4ueS2RnoQdshYBKcSa8Vt2UsL3VMqiFbjCqn1y0Xl_l4RalzP-rYmGYyq3oKJp_pjzcyfvG_oAowHWWi2fAxFmrp8ccbzlCSDsRxOfUtuOSpqHbepUoqSloxWZVWsKMDrmkWaLV09utnR2ACHfrQ0FS1yeSKkQNevmk8g" id="28">
                <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/2GOR8jFYc-c4ueS2RnoQdshYBKcSa8Vt2UsL3VMqiFbjCqn1y0Xl_l4RalzP-rYmGYyq3oKJp_pjzcyfvG_oAowHWWi2fAxFmrp8ccbzlCSDsRxOfUtuOSpqHbepUoqSloxWZVWsKMDrmkWaLV09utnR2ACHfrQ0FS1yeSKkQNevmk8g" id="29">
                <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/2GOR8jFYc-c4ueS2RnoQdshYBKcSa8Vt2UsL3VMqiFbjCqn1y0Xl_l4RalzP-rYmGYyq3oKJp_pjzcyfvG_oAowHWWi2fAxFmrp8ccbzlCSDsRxOfUtuOSpqHbepUoqSloxWZVWsKMDrmkWaLV09utnR2ACHfrQ0FS1yeSKkQNevmk8g" id="30">
                <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/2GOR8jFYc-c4ueS2RnoQdshYBKcSa8Vt2UsL3VMqiFbjCqn1y0Xl_l4RalzP-rYmGYyq3oKJp_pjzcyfvG_oAowHWWi2fAxFmrp8ccbzlCSDsRxOfUtuOSpqHbepUoqSloxWZVWsKMDrmkWaLV09utnR2ACHfrQ0FS1yeSKkQNevmk8g" id="31">
                <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/2GOR8jFYc-c4ueS2RnoQdshYBKcSa8Vt2UsL3VMqiFbjCqn1y0Xl_l4RalzP-rYmGYyq3oKJp_pjzcyfvG_oAowHWWi2fAxFmrp8ccbzlCSDsRxOfUtuOSpqHbepUoqSloxWZVWsKMDrmkWaLV09utnR2ACHfrQ0FS1yeSKkQNevmk8g" id="32">
            </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you ,I've tried this yesterday already and I don't know what to do next. How to do that effect. When clicking on the menu ,the current displayed set will move to left and fadeout and new one will fade in just like u did with translateX